# how to apply certain list index to sort in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have been asked to sort a `k messed array`
I have below code. I have to reduce the `complexity` from `nlogn to nlogk`.

```
arr = [3,2,1,4,5,6,8,10,9]
k = 2
def sortKmessedarr(arr, k):
    i = 1
    j = 0
    n = len(arr)
    while i < n:
        if arr[i] > arr[i-1]:
            pass
        else:
            arr[i-1:i+k].sort() # How to sort elements between two specific indexs
        i += 1
sortKmessedarr(arr, k)
print(arr)
```

I think if I apply this approach then it will become `nlogk`

But how to apply this `sort()` between two `indexes.`

I have also tried another approach like below:

```
arr = [3,2,1,4,5,6,8,10,9]
k = 2
def sortKmessedarr(arr, k):
    def merge(arr):
        arr.sort()
        print(arr)
    i = 1
    j = 0
    n = len(arr)
    while i < n:
        if arr[i] > arr[i-1]:
            pass
        else:
            merge(arr[i-1:i+k])#.sort()
        i += 1
sortKmessedarr(arr, k)
print(arr)
```

But still no luck

Comment: If your code works but you want people to suggest better options, your question is probably better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` with slice assignment to get the intended effect syntactically, but I am unsure of the impact on performance (memory or speed):

```
arr[i-1:i+k] = sorted(a[i-1:i+k])
```

Comment: It did work, then why it was not working with `.sort()`

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak Because `arr[i - 1: i + k]` returns a *new list*, which is sorted in-place. You never capture the new list, so it gets garbage collected. Essentially, that line of code does nothing useful.